# How to create spin effect using HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-shapes

I needed spinning effect on hover of that square, what i can get is written below.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainSquare">
  <div class="firstInnerSquare">
    <div class="lastInnerSquare">
      Hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mainSquare{
  width:160px;
  height:160px;
  background:black;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding:25px;
}
.firstInnerSquare{
  width:110px;
  height:110px;
  background:red;
  padding:25px;
}
.lastInnerSquare{
  text-align:center;
  width:110px;
  padding: 46px 0px;
  background:white;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83sxtgpL/)

Hope to get help.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: ever heard of css prop, animate?

Comment: i donit have much knowledge of css and animation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by using a single element and two pseudos. Make the 2 pseudo elements larger than the container element, position them behind the container and add a `rotate` animation to them.

**Note:** This is only a base sample that would help you get started. I would leave the fine tuning part for you to handle. You can read more about the CSS animation properties in [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation).

```css
.shape {
  position: relative; /* used to position the pseudos relative to the parent */
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 100px; /* required because children are larger than parent */
}
.shape:after,
.shape:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}
.shape:before {
  height: 125%; /* make one pseudo 25% larger than parent */
  width: 125%;
  top: -12.5%; /* 25/2 to make sure its center is same as the parent's */
  left: -12.5%; /* 25/2 to make sure its center is same as the parent's */
  background: red;
  z-index: -1; /* send it behind the parent */
}
.shape:after {
  height: 150%; /* make this pseudo larger than the parent and the other pseudo */
  width: 150%;
  top: -25%; /* 50/2 to make sure its center is same as the parent's */
  left: -25%; /* 50/2 to make sure its center is same as the parent's */
  background: black;
  z-index: -2; /* send it behind both the parent and other pseudo */
}

/* add animation when hovering on parent */
.shape:hover:before { 
  animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
}
.shape:hover:after {
  animation: rotate-rev 3s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg); /* some browsers don't display spin when it is 360 deg */
  }
}
@keyframes rotate-rev {
  to {
    transform: rotate(-359deg); /* reverse direction rotate */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='shape'></div>
```

Comment: @kishore.k.vaishnav: You can slow down the spin by increasing the `animation-duration`. After seeing your comment under the question, I'd recommend you to go through [this MDN page on animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation).

Answer (score 6):

Here's one with the original structure and just one keyframe statement:

All that needs changing, *per div*, is the animation duration and direction. The "middle" div's timing needs to be 50% of the outer/inner.

```css
.mainSquare {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background: black;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 25px;
  animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
}
.firstInnerSquare {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background: red;
  padding: 25px;
  animation: spin 1s infinite linear reverse;
}
.lastInnerSquare {
  text-align: center;
  width: 110px;
  padding: 46px 0px;
  background: white;
  animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mainSquare">
  <div class="firstInnerSquare">
    <div class="lastInnerSquare">
      Hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one. This just needs one keyframe :)